# How can I invoke multiple Robocopy.exe commands AsJobs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Don't beat me up to much guys, I was trying to understand the other similair questions asked about this issue, just wasn't able to decipher them.

I'm using the below code snipet to copy folders, seperately, on a "*remote*" computer using `Start-Job`:

```
$Folders = @('Desktop','Documents','Favorites','Links','Downloads','Music','Videos','Pictures','Contacts') 
    
    Foreach($Folder in $Folders){
        $ArgumentsArray  = @()
        $ArgumentsArray += "\\$Env:COMPUTERNAME\c$\Users\Abraham\$Folder"
        $ArgumentsArray += "C:\CopyBackup"
        $RoboCopy_Args   =  @("/E","/R:5","/W:1","/MT:13")
    
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe $args[0] "$($args[1])\$using:Folder" $using:RoboCopy_Args } -ArgumentList $ArgumentsArray -Name $Folder
    }
```

The code works as intended.

Now, the issue is when I try to *invoke* the command remotely using `Invoke-Command -AsJob`. Error reads:

> The pipeline was not run because a pipeline is already running. Pipelines cannot be run concurrently.

Which I tried to read and understand before coming here but, wasn't able to understand why it won't work. What's odd, is that the first folder in the `$Folders` array (*Desktop*) does get copied as a job, shows completed, but the other show failed immediately. So I ran `Receive-Job -Name Documents` and is where I got the above error.

- What does this have to do with the *pipeline*?
- Is there a work around solution?

*Failed Code:*

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop

$Folders = @('Desktop','Documents','Favorites','Links','Downloads','Music','Videos','Pictures','Contacts') 
    
    Foreach($Folder in $Folders){
        $ArgumentsArray  = @()
        $ArgumentsArray += "C:\Users\Abraham\$Folder"
        $ArgumentsArray += "C:\CopyBackup"
        $RoboCopy_Args   =  @("/E","/R:5","/W:1","/MT:13")
    
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe $args[0] "$($args[1])\$using:Folder" $using:RoboCopy_Args } -AsJob -ArgumentList $ArgumentsArray -Session $PSSession -JobName $Folder
    }
```

*`Get-Job` output:*

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
518    Desktop         RemoteJob       Running       True            DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
520    Documents       RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
522    Favorites       RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
524    Links           RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
526    Downloads       RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
528    Music           RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
530    Videos          RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
532    Pictures        RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
534    Contacts        RemoteJob       Failed        False           DESKTOP-OEREJ77       & C:\Windows\System32...
```

*I'd like to stick with running this "as jobs" due to the event produced by it, `StateChanged`, which im using for a different purpose.*

**EDIT:**
*I've decided to wrap it all into one single `Invoke-Command` and send it over, but it's still copying one at a time.*

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorAction Stop

    
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

    $Folders = @('Desktop','Documents','Favorites','Links','Downloads','Music','Videos','Pictures','Contacts') 
        foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {



            $ArgumentsArray  = @()
            $ArgumentsArray += "C:\Users\Abraham\$Folder"
            $ArgumentsArray += "C:\CopyBackup"
            $RoboCopy_Args   =  @("/E","/R:5","/W:1","/MT:13")
        
            Start-job {

                & C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe $args[0] "$($args[1])\$using:Folder" $using:RoboCopy_Args
            
            } -ArgumentList $ArgumentsArray -Name $Folder
        } 
} -AsJob -Session $PSSession -JobName $Folder
```

Comment: Could be related to invoke command to the same host multiple times? Why not invoke command once as job and use runspace inside the scriptblock?

Comment: @Santiago, too dumb to know how to do so lol

Comment: You also need to consider that robocopy might be over loading the disk / cpu on the remote host, I'm not sure if its a good a idea to backup multiple folders at the same time.

Comment: Just looking for the most efficient/fastest way to do it on a remote computer. I personally don't like the toll it takes on the cpu, but it's the best results I've been able to work with so far.

Comment: My understanding from that error is that only 1 remote pipeline can exists with the same host and I suspect that each job is considered a pipeline since each will be sending data independently.  If you don't mind running the jobs synchronously you could use a [queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs/).

Comment: If you would like the jobs to run asynchronously in parallel maybe submit all the jobs directly on the remote https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-7.1#start-a-remote-job-that-keeps-the-results-on-the-remote-computer.  Not sure how this will impact the other code you are running based on the StateChanged event though.

Comment: I will look into `queue`, some fancy stuff I wouldn't of come up with. Regarding your second comment, I was in  the midst of doing so already. See the edit. The only issue is just like you mentioned, i'm now unable to track the statechanged event.

Comment: If you what to run your script against many computers from one computer the simple answer is to use Splitpipline https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline  You can run you script against thousands of computers at the same time.

Comment: @Aaron, thank ya! I'm unable to download any modules at work.